# Order by and LIMIT both not working together in MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to Order by Desending and want to limit 30 in Query

**PHP CODE**

```
$page = $_POST['page'];
$cur_page = $page;
$page -= 1;
$per_page = 30;
$previous_btn = true;
$next_btn = true;
$first_btn = true;
$last_btn = true;
$start = $page * $per_page;

$query_pag_data = "SELECT * from titles LIMIT $start, $per_page ORDER BY id DESC";
```

ERROR : `MySql ErrorYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY id DESC' at line 1`

PS: i'm using pagination... so limiting 30 result like this

Comment: `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page` -- order comes first before limit

Comment: @491243 thanks 1+ for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

correct syntax is:

```
SELECT * from titles 
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT $start, $per_page
```

LIMIT at the end of the query.

Comment: thanks a lot..  i'm thinking some where :-) will select this as answer in few min

Answer (score 1):

change positions or `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY`, like:

```
$query_pag_data = "SELECT * from titles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page";
```

Comment: thanks! 1+ for you... Jason made this first :( so only 1+ for you

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the limit at the end of the query for proper syntax:

```
$query_pag_data = "SELECT * from titles ORDER BY id DESC  LIMIT $start, $per_page";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put ORDER BY statement first before LIMIT

Correct syntax is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM *table_name* WHERE *condition* ORBER BY *field_name* LIMIT *limit*;
```

Answer (score 0):

LIMIT statement should always come at the end of the query.